# Umbraco 7 - link to protected page inside another website redirects to ROOT page first time

Tags: umbraco, umbraco7

We are using Umbraco 7 and we have the following case for one of the tenants in the CMS:

Suppose we have our website hosted on the domain - https://foo.bar and we have the following protected page (cannot be accessed without authentication) - https://foo.bar/home/user-profile Suppose we have this other website (a foreign referrer) https://otherfoo.bar and inside it we have the absolute URL to the user profile mentioned above, embedded in the website.

The user has authenticated to https://foo.bar and now he is free to visit the https://foo.bar/home/user-profile but instead he does that via the absolute URL link on the foreign website. What the user experiences is - he is redirected to the root of the hierarchy of pages i.e. https://foo.bar/home/ regardless of the fact that he has previously authenticated. What's more interesting, is that refreshing the root page, redirects back to the intended visit of the original page https://foo.bar/home/user-profile.

We have conducted some tests and it turns out that using any foreign website to navigate to a page on our live dev/stage/prod environment always redirects to the root page first. However, that isn't happening when running a local instance on IIS Express. Now we are puzzled whether this is an Umbraco thing or an IIS thing? Any suggestions?

Comment: How are you accessing the protected page on the foreign website? Is it within an iFrame?

Comment: That actually is worth checking! However, why when we did our own tests and placed a link on differet site (one of the other tenants in umraco) with different domain, although not being in an iFrame, we got replicated the exact same behavior :(

Answer (score 0):

Have you setup URL redirects for HTTP -> HTTPS or www/non-www? which are called first?